# Explanation on nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

could someone please explain (step-by-step maybe) why Python (3.6) prints 3 for the following for loop?

```
n=0
for x in range(0, 2):             
    for y in range(x, 2):   
        n+=1
print(n)
```

## output: 3

Shouldn't it be 2?

```
first step: 
upper for loop: (0, 2), lower loop (0, 2), n=0+1=1
second step:
upper for loop: (1, 2), lower loop (1, 2), n=1+1=2

no third step, as (2, 2) is not executed
```

so where does the "3" come from?

Thanks

Comment: If the inner loop goes from 0 to 2 (0 and 1) then it increments the variable twice, not once.

Comment: Try printing x, y and n in each iteration of the inner loop to see what is going on.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. It is easy, but valid. So I voted up. To explain the result, I guess you understand that in the `for n in range(x, y)`, `x` is inclusive but `y` is not, so let us check it: `x` can be `0` and `1`, so the inner loop will be `for y in range(0, 2)` (y will have 2 values) and `for y in range (1, 2)` (y will have 1 value), so in total, `y` has 3 values, and inner loop iterates 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't execute the **inner loop iterations**; the first iteration for the outer loop causes the inner loop to iterate twice:

- iterate over `range(0, 2)`, `x = 0`,

  - iterate over `range(x == 0, 2)`, `y = 0`: `n = 1`
  - iterate over `range(x == 0, 2)`, `y = 1`: `n = 2`
  - iteration over `range(x == 0, 2)` ends.
- iterate over `range(0, 2)`, `x = 1`,

  - iterate over `range(x == 1, 2)`, `y = 1`: `n = 3`
  - iteration over `range(x == 1, 2)` ends.
- iteration over `range(0, 2)` ends.

This is something a debugger would have made clear, but you can also add more `print()` calls to make what happens more visible:

```
>>> n=0
>>> for x in range(0, 2):
...     print('x =', x)
...     for y in range(x, 2):
...         print('    y =', y)
...         n+=1
...         print('    n =', n)
...
x = 0
    y = 0
    n = 1
    y = 1
    n = 2
x = 1
    y = 1
    n = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is run twice, for `x=0` and `x=1`. `range()` doesn't include the final integer.

So for `x=0`, the inner loop iterates over `y=0` and `y=1`, and for `x=1`, it iterates over `y=1` only.

So there are 3 increments.

You can see this happen if you use a `print` statement:

```
n=0
for x in range(0, 2):
    print('x = {}'.format(x))
    for y in range(x, 2):
        print('y = {}'.format(y))
        n+=1
print('n = {}'.format(n))
```